# Trying to display "hh:mm" on a label from 2 textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I have two `TextBox` elements: `textbox1` for hour and `textbox2` for minutes. I've tried a lot of codes but they didn't work for me. I always ended up getting:

> Conversion from string "1" to type 'Date' is not valid.

I want to display time (in format `hh:mm`) on a label from two textboxes (`textbox1` and `textbox2`).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks

Comment: capital letters is usually regarded as shouting online - please don't do it.  Anyway, what code did you try? Sounds like maybe you tried to convert something into a date. But if you just want to re-display it, what's wrong with it just staying a string? It's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ~think~ you're trying to parse the values from the TextBoxes into a DateTime, and then display that in a Label?  If so, try something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text & ":" & TextBox2.Text, dt) Then
        Label1.Text = dt.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want only the Time portion displayed, then:

```
Label1.Text = dt.ToString("h:mm tt")
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH KIND SIR! This is my first time asking here, please excuse the way i asked.

Answer (score 0):

First of,u didn't mention any code u tried so far.However the solution would be :

```
 textbox1.text=DateTime.Now.ToString("HH")
 textbox2.text=DateTime.Now.ToString("mm")
```

The exception u r getting `Cannot convert string to date`,this can be fixed by using `ToString`.In the code, `HH` stands for `Hours` and `mm` stands for `minutes`
For better understanding , read the documentation of [DateTime.Now](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiE3Pyt2JPYAhWBPY8KHTaJBx0QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.datetime.now(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AOvVaw2nfyopRJQyWjSTNw7N-00p)

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding my senseless question. Appreciated.